# CardView is not showing properly in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to show card view in recycler view. I have compiled card view library in gradle file but the problem is card view is not showing there is no elevation and shadow it is showing simple plain view.

Here is my gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0
```

**Row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:contentPadding="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/userPostBook"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/userBookName"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is how it is showing in recyclerview:

[image]

As you can see in above screenshot there is no card view is showing in recyclerview.
Someone please let me know how can I overcome this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: add margin top and bottom to card view

Comment: Try to use **`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`** in your `CardView`

Comment: @Nilesh,thanks bro it worked I forgot to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`**  in your `CardView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:contentPadding="3dp">
```