# RecyclerView is not showing in Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a `NewsDetailsActivity` file that is displaying some news details. On top of the news details I want to display some `cardview` in a `recyclerview`. The recyclerView is not showing up but the worse part is that another `recyclerview` (that I have in the `MainActivity` is showing up in my `NewsDetailsActivity` like if If I am calling some `id` from my `NewsDetailsActivity`.

The only thing I want is to display some information on the top of the news details using the the recyclerview id `my_recycler_view_coin_details`

**NewsDetailsActivity**

```
package com.noticripto.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.noticripto.APIClientCoin;
import com.noticripto.adapters.CryptoListAdapter;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.noticripto.MainActivity;
import com.noticripto.R;
import com.noticripto.adapters.NewsAdapter;
import com.noticripto.model.HomePageModel;
  import com.noticripto.rest.ApiClient;
import com.noticripto.rest.ApiInterface;
import com.noticripto.retrofit.CryptoList;
import com.noticripto.retrofit.Datum;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class NewsDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



Toolbar toolbar;

TextView sourceName, newsTitle, newsDesc, newsDate, newsView,labelSimilar;
Button viewMore;
ImageView imagy,small_icn;


ProgressBar progressBar;


RecyclerView recyclerView3;
CryptoListAdapter adapterCoin2;
ApiInterface apiInterfaceCoin2;
List<Datum> cryptoList2 = null;

HomePageModel.News detailNews = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_detail);
    apiInterfaceCoin2 = APIClientCoin.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    recyclerView3 = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_coin_details);

    initViews();

    LoadNewsDetails();

    getCoinList();


}

private void LoadNewsDetails() {
    // Calling our api
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    params.put("id" , getIntent().getIntExtra("pid", 0) + "");


    Call<HomePageModel> call = apiInterface.getNewsDetailsById(params);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<HomePageModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HomePageModel> call, Response<HomePageModel> response) {

            // Update the news layout
            detailNews = response.body().getNews().get(0);
            newsTitle.setText(detailNews.getTitle());
            newsDesc.setText(NewsAdapter.removeHtml(detailNews.getPostContent()));

            if (detailNews.getImage().length() >=1){
                Glide.with(NewsDetailActivity.this)
                        .load(detailNews.getImage())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.image1)
                        .into(imagy);
            }else{
                imagy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HomePageModel> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}

private void initViews() {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon_arrow_back_white);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });


    }

    cryptoList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    adapterCoin2 = new CryptoListAdapter(cryptoList2);

   // sourceName = findViewById(R.id.source_name );
    newsTitle  = findViewById(R.id.news_title);
    newsDesc  = findViewById(R.id.news_desc);
    newsDate = findViewById(R.id.news_date);
    //newsView = findViewById(R.id.news_view);
    labelSimilar = findViewById(R.id.label_similar_news);

    //viewMore = findViewById(R.id.view_more);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    imagy =findViewById(R.id.news_image);
    //small_icn = findViewById(R.id.small_icn);




    recyclerView3 = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_coin_details);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager3 =new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager3);
    recyclerView3.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView3.setAdapter(adapterCoin2);

    adapterCoin2.notifyItemInserted(0);
    recyclerView3.scrollToPosition(0);


}


public void getCoinList() {

    Call<CryptoList> call2 = apiInterfaceCoin2.doGetUserList("20");
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<CryptoList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CryptoList> call, Response<CryptoList> response) 
{
            CryptoList list = response.body();

            cryptoList2.clear();
            cryptoList2.addAll(list.getData());

            adapterCoin2.notifyDataSetChanged();

            System.out.println("List getData = " + list.getData());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CryptoList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(NewsDetailActivity.this, "onFailure", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("XXXX", t.getLocalizedMessage());
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news_details_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share){

        if (detailNews != null){
            // Opening sharing options
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, detailNews.getTitle());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, detailNews.getPostContent());
            startActivity(i);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lo Sentimos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
  }
```

**crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewCoinDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/symbolNameDetails"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="roboto_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Symbol"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priceDetails"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/symbolNameDetails"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:textColor="#000" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**activity_news_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.NewsDetailActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/black"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/yellow"/>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar">




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view_coin_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/wrapper_cardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/news_title"
                        android:text="Titulo"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/wrapper"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/wrapper_news"
                        android:layout_below="@id/news_title"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/news_date"
                            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                            android:paddingStart="10dp"
                            android:text="Date"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:id="@+id/news_image"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_youtube"
                        android:layout_below="@id/wrapper_news"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/news_desc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/news_image"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="News Description"
                        android:firstBaselineToTopHeight="0dp"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/wrapper_cardview"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Similar News"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/label_similar_news"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/news_recy"
                android:layout_below="@id/label_similar_news"/>




        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>




    </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, I am trying to get the list from here:

**CryptoListAdapter**

```
package com.noticripto.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.noticripto.retrofit.Datum;
 import com.noticripto.R;

 import java.util.List;

 public class CryptoListAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<CryptoListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Datum> mData;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
ImageView arrowImage;
RelativeLayout layout;
RelativeLayout symbolBG;

// data is passed into the constructor
public CryptoListAdapter(List<Datum> data) {
    this.mData = data;
}

// Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crypto_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    layout = view.findViewById(R.id.relativeBG);
    symbolBG = view.findViewById(R.id.symbolBG);
    arrowImage = view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_img);


    return viewHolder;
}

// Involves populating data into the item through holder
// binds the data to the TextView in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    Datum datum = mData.get(position);

    TextView symbolName = holder.symbolName;
    symbolName.setText(" (" + datum.getSymbol() + ")");

    // Set item views based on your views and data model
    TextView name = holder.name;
    name.setText(datum.getName());
    TextView symbolNameDetails = holder.symbolNameDetails;
    symbolNameDetails.setText(datum.getSymbol());


    TextView price = holder.price;
    TextView priceDetails = holder.priceDetails;
    if(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice() >= 1) {
        price.setText("$" + String.format("%.2f", datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
       priceDetails.setText("$" + String.format("%.2f", datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
    }else{
        price.setText("$" + String.format("%f", datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
       priceDetails.setText("$" + String.format("%.2f", datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPrice()));
    }

    //TextView marketCap = holder.marketCap;
    //marketCap.setText("Market Cap: $" + String.format("%,d", 
Math.round(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getMarketCap())));

    //TextView volume24h = holder.volume24h;
    //volume24h.setText("Volume/24h: $" + String.format("%,d", 
Math.round(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getVolume24h())));

    //TextView textView1h = holder.textView1h;
    //textView1h.setText(String.format("1h: %.2f", 
datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange1h()) + "%");

    TextView textView24h = holder.textView24h;
    textView24h.setText(String.format("%.2f", datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h()) + "%");





    if(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h() < 0.0){
        //red
        textView24h.setText(String.format("%.2f", Math.abs(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h())) + "%");
        textView24h.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_white);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EA3943"));
        symbolBG.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EA3943"));

           priceDetails.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EA3943"));





    }else{
        //green
        textView24h.setText(String.format("%.2f", 
      Math.abs(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h())) + "%");
        textView24h.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_white);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18C784"));
        symbolBG.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18C784"));

        priceDetails.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#18C784"));

    }


    //TextView textView7d = holder.textView7d;
    //textView7d.setText(String.format("7d: %.2f", 
    datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange7d()) + "%");

  }

// Returns the total count of items in the list
// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

// Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
// Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener {
    // Your holder should contain a member variable
    // for any view that will be set as you render a row
    TextView name;
    TextView price;
    TextView marketCap;
    TextView volume24h;
    TextView textView1h;
    TextView textView24h;
    TextView textView7d;
    TextView symbolName;


    TextView priceDetails;
    TextView symbolNameDetails;

    // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
    // and does the view lookups to find each subview
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        //marketCap = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marketCap);
       // volume24h = itemView.findViewById(R.id.volume24h);
        //textView1h = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1h);
        textView24h = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView24h);
        //textView7d = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7d);
        symbolName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbolName);


        priceDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceDetails);
        symbolNameDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbolNameDetails);




        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, 
 getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// convenience method for getting data at click position
public Datum getItem(int id) {
    return mData.get(id);
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
  }
```

The log doesn't say anything helpful just that the list might be empty but the same list is working on the `MainActivity` so, I believe the problem is inside my `NewsDetailActivity`.

I also tried some of the answers and none of them helped me:

[RecyclerView is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067831/recyclerview-is-not-showing)
[RecyclerView is not showing items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646356/recyclerview-is-not-showing-items)
[CardView is not showing properly in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143086/cardview-is-not-showing-properly-in-recyclerview)

Again, i just want to display my list from `CryptoListAdapter` under the `NewsDetailActivity` toolbar...in a nice `cardview`

This is what I want to do...
[image]

Comment: "...another `recyclerview` (that I have in the `MainActivity` is showing up in my `NewsDetailsActivity`..." – Are you saying that the data is wrong, or the visual design of the `RecyclerView` and/or its items is wrong? Or all of it?

Comment: The data is correct. I just want to display what I have in `crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity.xml` inside my `NewsDetailActivity`

Comment: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crypto_list_item, parent, false);` – Is that what you mean? Did you mean to inflate that other layout there? In `CryptoListAdapter`'s `onCreateViewHolder()`?

Comment: the  `crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity.xml` inside the `NewsDetailActivity`

Comment: The thing is that I am not getting the data from `CryptoListAdapter` to `NewsDetailActivity` and I also can't display `crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity.xml` inside `NewsDetailActivity` but, `CryptoListAdapter` data is totally fine and displaying inside `MainActivity` therefore I think the problem is between `NewsDetailActivity` and `CryptoListAdapter`  and `crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity.xml` layout

Comment: You're not using `crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity` anywhere in the posted code. `CryptoListAdapter` has `crypto_list_item` hardcoded in it, so it will always show that item layout, no matter what `Activity` you're using an instance of `CryptoListAdapter` in. If you want to use `CryptoListAdapter` in multiple places, but with different item layouts, then you need to change your code to allow different layouts to be inflated in `onCreateView()`, in the line I showed above.

Comment: Yeeeeees..that's exactly what i need..damn..i was so focus on the tutorial that I didn't realize it. How do I make this work for any activity with different layouts?

Comment: A common way to do that would be to add a constructor parameter to pass the `R.layout`s with, and create a field for it; e.g., `private int layoutResId;`, `public CryptoListAdapter(List<Datum> data, int layoutResId) { ... this.layoutResId = layoutResId; }`. Then, change that inflate call to use that field: `... inflater.inflate(layoutResId, ...);`. Follow me?

Comment: Jeje so so... can you please provide an example. I got the idea..its just from where will i will be calling or passing the layoutId

Comment: Well, let's step back a second, because I assumed something that I shouldn't have. My suggestion of simply substituting different layouts is only going to work if both `crypto_list_item` and `crypto_list_item_in_detail_activity` have `View`s with all the same IDs in each. That is, they both show all of the same data, they just look different. Is that what you mean to do? If so, then this will work. If not, and they are supposed to be displaying different data in each `Activity`, then it sounds like you actually want separate `Adapter` classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234476/discussion-between-maduro-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple and normal! you fill your array in `getCoinList()` but set adapter for RecyclerView in `initViews()` in this way your array not filled yet but you pass it to your recycler! , you should get your array first , then pass it to adapter and set adapter to RecyclerView.

Comment: When you say get the array first..where should I do that? because I thought that getting the array in `initViews()` it was getting the array first. Can you please provide some code example base on my methods. Thanks,

Comment: I removed the recyclerview from `onCreate` and put it on `initViews` but still saying: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Everything is working. Thanks for your help